# Nodejs global variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

I have a variable called `username` in a post route within my node.js server-side code (accessed through a form submission) and I would like to use this same variable in another post route.

```
app.post("/login", function(req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    ...
});
```

```
//Another app.post route
```

Is there any way I could do this?

Comment: This seems like it would be **very** broken. If someone hit the other post route first, then it wouldn't be defined. If Bob hit `/login`, then `Alice` hit `/login`, then `Bob` hit `/give-all-my-money-to-charity` then Bob would have just spent all of Alice's money. Global variables are bad.

Comment: Use a sane authentication system. http://www.passportjs.org/

Comment: You need session. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_sessions.htm

Comment: @Quentin  thanks I will look into this

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is that first you initialize global variable in express app

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.username = "";
    next();
});
```

set this variable in post route

```
app.post("/login", function(req, res) {
 global.username = req.body.username;
});
```

Comment: There is no point in setting `res.locals.username` and then never using it.

Comment: The second half of your answer does answer [the literal question asked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), but it doesn't seem likely that it will solve any real problem the OP has (and Deep Kakkar already said everything you did there two hours earlier). There's no point in having a global variable to track the user who logged in most recently.